# How to clear chart completely in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I'm loading a store dynamically to a chart, my problem is that when the new chart is loaded, the old one (bars/lines) is still showing behind the new one.
This is how I remove the old chart :

```
    var removeChart = function (chart) {
            var series = chart.series.items, surface = chart.surface,
                length = series.length, len = surface.groups.keys.length,
                array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                array = Ext.Array.merge(array, series[i].group.keys);
            chart.series.clear();
            for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                surface.items.getByKey(array[j]).destroy();
                };
            for (var t = 0; t < len; t++)
                surface.groups.items[t].destroy();
        };
```

Then I call `removeChart(chart);` and finally add new series config and finish with `chart.redraw();`

What am I doing wrong please??

Comment: How exactly do you "load the store dynamically"? That's probably the part that is causing problem, you're not supposed to go so low level just to change a chart's data...

Comment: I have the same problem. `store.load()` is loading the store fine and it is drawing the new line, but the old line is still visible!
The store is loaded fine, I can see it has records and they are okay. Obviously, the chart is drawing them fine. But it forgets to remove the old lines.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to remove the chart to accomplish what you want.

Just reload the store, add the series, and redraw.

When you do it this way, you'll also get a cool animation (if you want animation).